# extract only those rows records that is appeared more than one time in a day in time series

Tags: python

Data looks like:

```
ID  Date    Time
1   2018-04-02  7:00:11
2   2018-04-02  8:23:32
1   2018-04-04  9:34:09
3   2018-04-09  12:24:54
4   2018-04-13  16:23:01
1   2018-04-02  8:23:32
2   2018-04-02  9:34:09
3   2018-04-10  12:24:54
2   2018-04-02  16:23:01
2   2018-04-18  7:34:45
```

Expected results:

```
1   2018-04-02  7:00:11
1   2018-04-02  8:23:32
2   2018-04-02  8:23:32
2   2018-04-02  9:34:09
2   2018-04-02  16:23:01
```

Comment: Is your data in a file? can you sort it? How large is your data?

Comment: @yukashimahuksay Doesn't look sorted to me

Comment: Thank for your comments. I have bus smart card data and want to study trip chaining or trip sequences. The question i posted just included a sample data but the code i will use for big data of passengers smart card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
df[df.duplicated(['Date'], keep=False)]
```

**Result**

```
         Date      Time
0  2018-04-02   7:00:11
1  2018-04-02   8:23:32
5  2018-04-02   8:23:32
6  2018-04-02   9:34:09
8  2018-04-02  16:23:01
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I am looking for code for something like: To extract the IDs that appeared more than one time in a particular day at different times of the day.

Comment: Add ID into the list to check for duplicated ID and Date as a whole, print(set(df[df.duplicated(['ID', 'Date'], keep=False)]['ID']))

Comment: I got it. It work for me. Thank you for your response to my query.